# Listen to 'invalid' event on a React component

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

I have a React input component and I'd like to use HTML5 Constraint Validation to validate user input after each blur.

```
var TextField = React.createClass({

    handleValidation: function () {
        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.textField).checkValidity();
        //TODO listen on invalid event
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <input ref="textField" onBlur={this.handleValidation} />
        )
    }
});
```

Comment: what do you mean "listen on invalid event"? Is this a JS exception?

Comment: I mean this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/invalid

Comment: Is there a question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason for listening to this event?

"checkValidity() method, which returns false if the element fails to satisfy any of its constraints, or true otherwise." [MDN source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#Constraint_Validation_API)

So you can just check if this function returns false.

```
if (!React.findDOMNode(this.refs.textField).checkValidity()) {
  // not valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting an event listener in the componentDidMount function... maybe something like this?

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  React.findDOMNode(this.refs.textField).addEventListener("invalid", function () {
    //do something here
  });
},
```

Just keep in mind if you navigate to another component you should remove the event listeners first. Hope this helps.